# Find computer name by username (check where the user is logon to)

Tags: c#, active-directory

I built a windows form application that receive IP and represents the computer name and the opposite.

However, I don't know if it's possible to enter username, and then recieve the IP or the computer name that the user is login to (if he login).

Loop through all the computers in the domain is not an option to me because it will takes so long. Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like a security bug if you can. is it possible to query the domain controller?

Comment: @kenny No. I thought it impossible also. But, if I have the ip or the computer name, I can get the username that login to?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple users can be logged into a Windows PC - how do you know which user you want?

From the command line on a PC, you can run `query user` to list the logged in users. Using `PSExec` you can run the command on a remote computer and get a response back.

If you are running in the context of the user, you can use the environment variable `USERNAME` to get the current user.

If you have Remote Registry services running, you can remotely query the Event Log and check Security Auditing events that correspond to logon and logoff on a particular PC.

You can also use the `PSLoggedOn` tool to query loaded registry hives and get usernames, if you have Remote Registry services running.

If you have AD controllers, you can scan their security logs and look for logon records for users from PCs.